# Reference Parent MenuItem in ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, viewmodel, datacontext

I am trying to bind an auto-created menu item's command to an ICommand exposed by the parent MenuItem's ViewModel.  The following is hopefully a good representation of what I have:

Custom Control:

```
class MyMenuItem : MenuItem {}
```

ViewModels:

```
class ParentVM
{
    public IEnumerable<ChildVM> Children { get; set; }
    public ICommand TheCommand { get; set; }
}

class ChildVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Global style for custom control:

```
<Style TargetType="namespace:MyMenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Some Text"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding [parent].TheCommand}"/>
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Consuming in context menu:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <namespace:MyMenuItem DataContext="{Binding AParentVM}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

I need to know what goes into the line with [parent].  Child menu items do get created and their name shows right, which tells me that I have the right DataContext at the top level because "Children" bound right, and I have the right DataContext at the bottom level because "Name" bound right.  I expected a RelativeSource binding using an AncestorType of MyMenuItem would be what was needed, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.TheCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type namespace:MyMenuItem}}}"/>
```

Alternatively, give the child VM a reference to the parent, or to the command that it needs to expose.

Comment: I believe you need to bind to `DataContext.TheCommand` so you bind to `MyMenuItem.DataContext.TheCommand` instead of trying to bind to `MyMenuItem.TheCommand`, which doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks Rachel, that was it.  Too much xaml this weekend.  Make it an answer and I'll award.

Comment: +1 for updated answer. @PatrickV this answer is correct, so I won't post a separate answer :)